# How to properly setup pyarrow for python 3.7 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, hadoop, hdfs, pyarrow

I've been trying pyarrow installation via pip (`pip install pyarrow`, and, as suggested Yagav: `py -3.7 -m pip install --user pyarrow`) and conda (`conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow`, also used `conda install pyarrow`) , building lib from src (using conda environment and some magic, which I don’t really understand), but all the time, after installation (with no errors) it ends with one and the same problem, when I call:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host='my_host', user='my_user@my_host', kerb_ticket='path_to_kerb_ticket')
```

it fails with next message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py", line 209, in connect
    extra_conf=extra_conf)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py", line 37, in __init__
    _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py", line 135, in _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath
    classpath = _hadoop_classpath_glob(hadoop_bin)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py", line 162, in _hadoop_classpath_glob
    return subprocess.check_output(hadoop_classpath_args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid win32 application
```

At first I was thinking, that there is a problem with libhdfs.so from Hadoop 2.5.6, but it seems that I was wrong about that.
I guess, there is a problem not in the pyarrow or subprocess, but some system variables or dependencies.

Also I have manually defined system variables as `HADOOP_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `KRB5CCNAME`

Comment: _I've been trying pyarrow installation via pip and conda, building lib from src_ Can you expand on that? How exactly did you install it? Did it succeed?

Comment: As I expanded the text, I’ve used the following methods: pip install pyarrow, py -3.7 -m pip install --user pyarrow, conda install pyarrow, conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow, also builded pyarrow from src and dropped it into site-packages of python conda folder

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it by myself.
As I've been thinking, the broblem was in system environvent variables, it needs to have `CLASSPATH` variable, which contains paths to all .jar files of hadoop client, you can get them using `hadoop classpath` or `hadoop classpath --glob` in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

This one is the solution :

```
def _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath():
    import subprocess

    if 'hadoop' in os.environ.get('CLASSPATH', ''):
        return

    if 'HADOOP_HOME' in os.environ:
        hadoop_bin = os.path.normpath(os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'])  +"/bin/"  #'{0}/bin/hadoop'.format(os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'])
    else:
        hadoop_bin = 'hadoop'

    os.chdir(hadoop_bin)
    hadoop_bin_exe = os.path.join(hadoop_bin, 'hadoop.cmd')
    print(hadoop_bin_exe)
    classpath = subprocess.check_output([hadoop_bin_exe, 'classpath', '--glob'])
    os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = classpath.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the code n the cmd so you install pyarrow correctely.

py -3.7 -m pip install --user pyarrow

after installing try the the code.

Comment: It didn't helped, the error message is still there and the same